# How to declare a variable in a loop and make it available in the template file

Tags: loop, get-template-part

I was faced with a minor issue but can't solve it myself. I need to add the value on the variable after all loop iterations. And nothing problem, but I need to use this variable in the other file. for example:

```
while( have_posts() ) {
        the_post();
        $x = '';
        $x++;
        get_template_part( 'content', 'right' );
    }
```

Now I need to get the $x value with iteration in content-right.php I try to declare a variable into this file but in this case no iteration. Is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are re-initializing your `$x` variable on every iteration of the loop. Maybe you want to move its initialization outside the loop? To get `$x` variable value in the `content-right.php` file you can declare it as [global](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php):

```php
global $x;
$x = 0;
while( have_posts() ) {
    the_post();
    $x++;
    get_template_part( 'content', 'right' );
}
```

Then you can use it in the `content-right.php` file:

```php
global $x;
# ... here you can use $x variable value
```